# Luckey Draw number meter view Android

Tags: android, view

I needed to Create a view for show luckey draw number meter but i dont have any idea for it.

The same idea used in CrownIt app in Weekly Rush.

I added video for better understanding.

You can download it from [Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndeatjk4xskxs8h/device-2017-06-23-114657.mp4?dl=0).

Help me to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Check This NumericWheel http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html

Comment: Thanks all... I want view like [Wheel-Ticket](https://github.com/spinaki/android-wheel-ticker) but with digit background...

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to lucky draw number. You can also customize this as per your requirement.

https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView

Look at this one also https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5915

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I also get this but it it flip digit view but i needed view in which digits are spinning like luckey drow numbers spinning.